# React useEffect dependency is triggering update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following React component:

```js
interface Props {
    cpi: number;
    onCpiChange: (value?: number) => void;
}

const Assumption: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const [cpiValue, setCpiValue] = useState<number>();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.cpi != cpiValue) {
            setCpiValue(props.cpi);
        }
    }, [props.cpi]);

    return (
        <FormattedNumberInput
            value={cpiValue}
            onBlur={() => props.onCpiChange(cpiValue)}
            onValueChange={setCpiValue}
        />
    );
};

export default Assumption;
```

The `useEffect` is complaining that it's missing the `cpiValue` - and as it's not in the dependency array it doesn't update when comparing using `props.cpi != cpiValue`. I don't want this `useEffect` to trigger every time the `cpiValue` changes. How would I have this `useEffect` respond only to when props.cpi changes yet still have access to the other variables required such as `cpiValue` with which I'm comparing against?

Additionally when initially learning React Hooks I learned that there are ways of controlling when a `useEffect` will trigger as follows:

1. If you don't include a dependency array it will update on every render.
2. If you provide an empty array it should update only on the first time the component loads
3. If you provide any members inside the array the `useEffect` will trigger every time that one of these variables were to update.

The only one of these that makes sense is the third option. Options one and two have no scope to variables outside of the `useEffect` if you don't include them in the dependency array, but then adding the required variables to the dependency array changes the definition of the `useEffect` from 1 or 2 to 3. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the conditional test *into* the state updater and this should remove it as a dependency. Using a functional state update you can use the `cpiValue` of the previous state and use a ternary to either return new `cpi` props value *or* the previous state `cpiValue` value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCpiValue(cpiValue => props.cpi !== cpiValue ? props.cpi : cpiValue);
}, [props.cpi]);
```

In my opinion I don't think the conditional test is necessary as it seems any time `props.cpi` updates and triggers the `useEffect` callback that you currently only enqueue an update if it *isn't* already equal to the current state. Why not just always update the local state cached version of `props.cpi` when it updates?

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCpiValue(props.cpi);
}, [props.cpi]);
```

If they are actually already equal then they will still be equal after. React can [bail out of state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) if the value is the same.

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with `useMemo`.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks, and has definitely helped me out of this bind. I do question how you'd solve it for if it were another non-related value say that wasn't going to be accessed via a previous state? With respect to state updates, I wasn't aware of React bailing out of state updates if the value is the same. I've always ended up in infinite loops, but I'll give it another look. Thanks again.

Comment: @Misanthropist I think the typical cause of render looping is unconditionally updating a value (like state) in an `useEffect` callback that is part of the effect's dependency array. In the answer there is no cycle between updating local state and dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

The `useState` will trig rerender every time when it called. And the props changed will also trig the component rerender.
May be you can use the `useState(initialize)`.

```
interface Props {
    cpi: number;
    onCpiChange: (value?: number) => void;
}

const Assumption: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const [cpiValue, setCpiValue] = useState<number>(props.cpi);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     if (props.cpi != cpiValue) {
    //         setCpiValue(props.cpi);
    //     }
    // }, [props.cpi]);

    return (
        <FormattedNumberInput
            value={cpiValue}
            onBlur={() => props.onCpiChange(cpiValue)}
            onValueChange={setCpiValue}
        />
    );
};

export default Assumption;
```